# "CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.1.199:8081 not permitted by network security policy."

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, https, expo

I use Expo Go and React Native to build a mobile application. In this mobile application, I use a Laravel API. Thanks to this API, all my backend is managed, and this API is accessible at the IP address 192.168.1.199:8081. The Laravel application is hosted locally on a PHP server that runs continuously. During the development of my application, I didn't encounter any issues with my API until the production phase with the APK of the application. At first, I thought it was a DNS problem, which is why I used the IP address.

Logs :

```
12-19 14:18:01.846 29275 29323 I ReactNativeJS:   _perfKey: 'network_XMLHttpRequest_http://192.168.1.199:8081/api/user/UsersLogin',
12-19 14:18:01.846 29275 29323 I ReactNativeJS:   _response: 'CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.1.199 not permitted by network security policy',
12-19 14:18:01.846 29275 29323 I ReactNativeJS:   _url: 'http://192.168.1.199:8081/api/user/UsersLogin',
```

However, I learned from my logs that it was related to the HTTP protocol used. The APK actually expects an HTTPS protocol. Two solutions were available to me: either switch the Laravel application to HTTPS or allow the APK to access HTTP addresses. I tried both solutions without success. I would like more details on how to allow the reading of HTTP protocols. I searched on my own, and they all modify their AndroidManifest.xml file, a file I don't have with Expo, and the Expo documentation with plugins is too vague for me; I can't understand how it works. Can you help me?

[2024-01-09]
I tried to use CertBot and Let's Encrypt to certify my website. The problem is that my website is not in .com, .net or other "public" domains. So this solution did not work. Same thing for a local certificate then installed as a personal license. I'm now out of ideas.